# SQL select the min and max values of the intersecting interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, intervals

In MsSQL 2014 I`ve got a table  containing intervals of values

```
  Col1  Col2
  1     3
  2     4
  7     12
  7     15
  14    21
```

I need to get the maximum and minimum values of the intersecting intervals.
Expected result:

```
  Col1  Col2
  1     4
  7     21
```

Have ideas how to build a query?

The first row describes the interval from 1 to 3. That is, the interval contains the values 1, 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.8, 2.9, 3.
The interval on the second row contains the values 2, 2.1, 2.2 ...3.9, 4.
the intersection of the intervals in the first two rows contains 2, 2.1,...2.9, 3.

And in the fifth line the interval has no intersections with the interval from the third row, but the fifth row and the third have intersections with the fourth row.

I need to find such intervals and get their minimum and maximum values. I know how to do this with the cursor, but can I do it with a SQL query?

Comment: Can you elaborate the term "Intersecting"?

Comment: What do you mean by intersecting intervals? Because there are no common elements in the two columns. Explain your logic bit more

Comment: "of the intersecting intervals" - Your expected result shows *only* intervals which have at least one intersection. Is this a requirement, or is the question for the maximum intervals while merging intersecting ones?

Comment: Also, since this looks like 'homework', what have you tried?

Comment: Ask yourself: What is the *condition* required for two intervals to be "intersecting"?

Comment: What is the meaning of "Intersecting"? Can you Explain in more?

Comment: Added description of intersecting intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  In this case, you want to find where the "islands" start (that is no previous overlap):

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, 3), (2, 4), (7, 12), (7, 15), (14, 21)
           ) v(col1, col2)
     )
select grp, min(col1), max(col2)
from (select t.*, sum(case when prev_col2 >= col1 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by col1, col2) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(col2) over (order by col1, col2) as prev_col2
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ac55266bc72ee7f263254c69c826a8c) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It would require a self-join, so use different alias names.  Also, to prevent low/hi and hi/low retrieval of same rows, have the second alias only with a value greater than the first... Maybe something like

```
select
      low.Col1,
      hi.Col2
   from
      YourTable low
         JOIN YourTable hi
            on low.Col1 < hi.Col1
            AND hi.Col1 < low.Col2
```